# Check if a specific file with a specific name is running?

Tags: ubuntu, process, filenames, php

I am wondering is it possible to check if a specific file with a specific name is running? I see a lot of various cases that show PID's rather than a filename but would rather take a filename route. For instance lets say a file called test.php is being executed via PHP command (in this case lets just pretend this file is just an infinite loop just so the file remains running indefinitely). Is there any command that I can write out that will let me know that this particular file is currently being executed? If this is not doable can I see all PHP files that are currently being ran? Currently using Ubunutu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Does the filename need to be the command that's executing? Or could you have a process `.../php test.php` and do you want to match it?

Comment: I just want to know if a specific file is being executed. I was using PHP as an example just for clarification. I might want to check various file types such as test.py, test.js, etc....I am not sure if where its situated at in my directory will make a difference? you tell me? @JeffSchaller

Comment: In `php something.py`, it'd be precise to say that `php` is executing the commands in `something.py`; similarly, if there's a process `sed /something/ test.php`, `sed` is executing -- test.php is *not* being executed.  Scripts of various kinds can also be executed directly (`/path/to/test.php`), so I was curious what situation you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pgrep`:

```
pgrep -f test.php
```

This will output the PID of your command.

Alternative:

```
ps aux | grep '[t]est\.php'
```

This will output the corresponding line of `ps aux`.

Comment: This actually turned out to be my solution. I was overthinking my problem thank you for the help

Comment: Note that this will return the processes that have `test.php` anywhere in their process name; some false positives include `/some/other/test.php/process-name arg1 arg2` and `sed /script/ test.php` -- neither of which indicate that `test.php` is *executing*.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
processname='login'
if [ "$(pgrep $processname)x" != "x" ]
then
    echo $processname is running
else
    echo $processname is NOT running
fi
```

An alternate version that uses the exit status rather than the return value, and also uses a more compact syntax

```
#!/bin/sh
processname='login'
pgrep $processname > /dev/null
test $? -eq 0 && echo "$processname is running" || echo "$processname is NOT running"
```

Comment: `pgrep` exits with a zero exit status if finding the process, otherwise with a non-zero exit status, so no need to use `[ ... ]` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using killall

```
killall -0 -q test.php && echo test.php is running
```

Despite the name of the command, the process is not killed.